# add delegates and call MulticastDelegate by reflection

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following scenario
I have a loop which has an Update callback which several objects use CreateDelegate to creat their own delegates and add themselves to it at runtime.
now I want to avoid creating N delegates for N objects so I thought using a multi cast open delegate I can create one delegate
add all instances to it and call it,
How can I do it via reflection 
I create the delegate using CreateDelegate from my method info once and then call NewMultiCastDelegate via reflection and send it the list of objects but things go wron when I call invoke with another dummy instance to call it, unprotected memory violation exception is thrown.

How can I do it?

I can not do it without reflection since my objects methods will be known at runtime and anyone with an Update method should be called by this loop manager.

This is for a game engine

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you're trying to do? It doesn't sound like anything that would require delegates or reflection.

Comment: I am emulating unity game engine's behavior so have to do it with reflection and like that. the engine finds methods like Update() and LateUpdate() via reflection without any interfaces/base classes

Comment: Well, you noted that the objects register themselves - and they obviously know themselves at compile time. So they just need to pass a delegate to themselves - what you do with that delegate is up to you (for example, to make a multicast delegate, you can just use `+=`). But in the end, there will always be multiple delegates, and they will always be called in a loop one after another - it's not like the CLR has a magical method that allows it to run all the delegates at once; it simply executes them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

There are two issues with using MulticastDelegate + open instance delegates.

1. It's not possible to invoke open instance delegates with multiple unrelated types. Take types `A` and `B`, each with an `Update` method. An open instance delegate of `A.Update` can be invoked with instances of `A` (or types derived from `A`), but not with instances of `B`. That's because `A.Update` and `B.Update` are unrelated as far as the .NET runtime is concerned.
2. Multiple open instance delegates can be combined in a single MulticastDelegate, but this doesn't fit your use case. You want to call the `Update` method on each instance in a list. Invoking a MulticastDelegate will sequentially call each delegate in its invocation list with the same parameter list. So a MulticastDelegate with multiple open instance delegates could be used to invoke a list of methods on a single instance, but not a single method on a list of instances. Does that make sense?

I assume you're trying to speed up adding a Unity Component to your engine emulator, and that's why you want to stop calling `CreateDelegate` for each one.

Instead of using a MulticastDelegate, you can achieve a speedup by creating open instance delegates the first time a type is added, then caching those delegates for reuse.

Here's some code along those lines:

```
public class ComponentEventAggregator
{
    public void AddComponent(object component)
    {
        var typeGroup = this.GetTypeGroup(component.GetType());
        typeGroup.AddComponent(component);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var typeGroup in this.typeGroupsByType.Values)
        {
            typeGroup.Update();
        }
    }

    public void RemoveComponent(object component)
    {
        TypeGroup typeGroup;
        if (this.typeGroupsByType.TryGetValue(component.GetType(), out typeGroup))
        {
            typeGroup.RemoveComponent(component);
        }
    }

    private TypeGroup GetTypeGroup(Type type)
    {
        TypeGroup typeGroup;
        if (!this.typeGroupsByType.TryGetValue(type, out typeGroup))
        {
            typeGroup = TypeGroup.Create(type);
            this.typeGroupsByType[type] = typeGroup;
        }

        return typeGroup;
    }

    private abstract class TypeGroup
    {
        public abstract void Update();
        // ... LateUpdate, OnApplicationPause, etc.

        public abstract void AddComponent(object component);
        public abstract void RemoveComponent(object component);

        // Create a TypeGroup<T> for the specified type
        public static TypeGroup Create(Type type)
        {
            var closedDelegatesType = typeof(TypeGroup<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });
            var typeDelegates = closedDelegatesType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[0]);
            return (TypeGroup)typeDelegates;
        }
    }

    private class TypeGroup<T> : TypeGroup where T : class
    {
        public TypeGroup()
        {
            this.update = CreateOpenDelegate("Update");
            this.lateUpdate = CreateOpenDelegate("LateUpdate");
            this.onApplicationPause = CreateOpenDelegate<bool>("OnApplicationPause");
            // ...other Unity events
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            if (this.update != null)
            {
                foreach (var component in this.components)
                {
                    this.update(component);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void AddComponent(object component)
        {
            var t = component as T;
            if (t != null)
            {
                this.components.Add(t);
            }
        }

        public override void RemoveComponent(object component)
        {
            var t = component as T;
            if (t != null)
            {
                this.components.Remove(t);
            }
        }

        private static Action<T> CreateOpenDelegate(string functionName)
        {
            var method = GetMethod(functionName, Type.EmptyTypes);
            if (method == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), method);
        }

        private static Action<T, TArg1> CreateOpenDelegate<TArg1>(string functionName)
        {
            var method = GetMethod(functionName, new[] { typeof(TArg1) });
            if (method == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return (Action<T, TArg1>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T, TArg1>), method);
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetMethod(string functionName, Type[] parameterTypes)
        {
            return typeT.GetMethod(functionName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, parameterTypes, null);
        }

        private readonly Action<T> update;
        private readonly Action<T> lateUpdate;
        private readonly Action<T, bool> onApplicationPause;
        private List<T> components = new List<T>();
        private static readonly Type typeT = typeof(T);
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, TypeGroup> typeGroupsByType = new Dictionary<Type, TypeGroup>();
}
```

This gives a 50X speedup to add a Component compared to `Delegate.CreateDelegate` on my PC.

Test times with 1 million `A` and 1 million `B` instances:

```
10892ms add closed delegates with CreateDelegate for all Components
   11ms Update via the closed delegates
  187ms add all Components to the type-based aggregator
   30ms Update via the open instance delegates (i.e. Update on aggregator)
```

The `Update` method in both `A` and `B` increments a private static int.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

It sounds like you would be better off exposing a C# event on your loop manager and adding subscriptions that call the Update methods. Alternately all the types with the Update method could implement an IUpdater interface, then you'd send a list of IUpdater instances to the loop manager instead of a list of objects.

Assuming you really do have some other good reason for using reflection...

```
class Program
{
    public class Updater
    {
        public void AddUpdateListeners(object[] listeners)
        {
            Func<object, MethodInfo> getUpdateMethod = l =>
                l.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("Update", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[0], null);
            listeners
                .Select(listener => new { listener, update = getUpdateMethod(listener) })
                .Where(l => l.update != null)
                .Select(l => Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UpdateDelegate), l.listener, l.update))
                .OfType<UpdateDelegate>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(d => this.updateDel += d);
        }

        public void PublishCallbacks()
        {
            var handler = this.updateDel;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler();
            }
        }

        private delegate void UpdateDelegate();
        private UpdateDelegate updateDel;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var updater = new Updater();
        updater.AddUpdateListeners(new object[] { new A(), new B(), });
        updater.PublishCallbacks();
    }

    public class A
    {
        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A updated");
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B updated");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haveto do it like that, I'm emulating the behavior of Unity game engine which does it with reflection and like this.
I could create one delegate per object after finding the method and then assign it to the delegate in the loop (I have that working actually) but I want to avoid creating one delegate per object (Delegate.CreateDelegate)

Comment: You cannot just give raw object instances to a MulticastDelgate. Why don't you want to create the delegate instances? Pressure on the garbage collector? You could invoke the MethodInfo instances directly when you publish updates.

Comment: Of course, events *are* multicast delegates. Though I do agree that they provide a bit nicer interface (in particular, not allowing you to influence the other delegates in the multicast). Still, for something like this, I don't think they're quite enough - you need to make some way of cleaning up after the objects as they go dead.

Comment: @JoelV.Earnest-DeYoung Thanks man! First of all those methods Update() Start() don't have parameters.
Your first item in the list above already limits me because different types need their own delegates, on the second point
so a multi cast delegate can not have a  list of targets in it's invocation list and call the same method in all of them with the same params (i.e. no params)?

Comment: And yes I'm trying to releave GC from allocations as much as possible. And invoking via MethodInfo.Invoke is hell much slower.

Comment: I think you're going to have choose between different trade-offs: speed vs code complexity, speed vs more GC pressure, AddComponent speed vs Update speed. In my updated approach I've avoided allocating anything when adding a Unity Component to the engine (except for the first instance of a Component type).

Comment: A MulticastDelegate is basically a list of functions with the same argument signature. With closed delegates, you can use a single MulticastDelegate, but then you're stuck calling CreateDelegate for each Unity Component instance - exactly what you're trying to avoid. Open delegates avoid CreateDelegate, but require you to handle each Component type with it's own delegate. Trade-offs